# VBE6.DLL Crashes Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

When we open a Template created in Word 2003, with Word 2007, vbe6.dll crashes Word 2007.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be related to Word 2007 add-ins. This [article](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/apperrors/problemsstartingword.htm) titled "Solving Crashing Problems in MS Word" suggests some solutions. Especially read [this](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/apperrors/problemsstartingword.htm#AntiVirus_Woes) section.

Comment: This article did no good. We still experience the crashing of Word 2007 when opening a Word 2003 Template.